# Android 3.0 Use Physical Keyboard Setting

Tags: android, keyboard, settings, android-3.0-honeycomb, input-devices

Background:

I recently purchased a Motorola XOOM Tablet along with the Desktop Dock and Bluetooth Keyboard accessories.

The dock and keyboard work great, but when I take the tablet off the dock to move away from my desk, the keyboard still remains paired with the device and I have to manually change the settings to use the soft keyboard. The same goes for when I set it back on the dock, I need to manually switch it back. It's not a *huge* problem, but it would be nice not to have to think about it.

So I tried downloading an app from the market that simply toggled Bluetooth on and off when connected or disconnected from a power source, which worked well for a while, but the background service would die after period and become useless until I manually restarted that.

TO THE POINT: I'm trying to write a little app/service for my tablet that will recognize when it has been docked/undocked and switch the "Use Physical Keyboard" setting accordingly.

I have started with a BroadcastReciever to recognize the Dock State:

```
public class DockBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String DOCK_STATE_LABEL = "android.intent.extra.DOCK_STATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String message = (extras.getInt(DOCK_STATE_LABEL) == Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED) ? "Undocked" : "Docked";

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to update the setting after the event is fired. I've poked around some examples using *InputMethodManager*, but all the methods seem to need a specific *EditText* or some other input to bind to.

Furthermore, I can't seem to find a corresponding constant that represents that setting anywhere in the docs, but graphically, it is located here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esFaw.png

Can anyone help me out with this?

I would like for there to be a solution for changing the setting, but I am open to other ideas as well.

Comment: Maybe the setting is not accessible programmatically, can't you just turn off bluetooth?

Comment: I could, but I figured as long as I was writing it myself, I'd target the specific issue of the Keyboard just in case I (or someone else) would like to utilize the Bluetooth for something else (headphones, streaming, etc.) once the tablet has been undocked

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does something similar. It can toggle wifi and bluetooth based on power.

You'll need to register some of this stuff in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

http://code.google.com/p/futonic-wifioncall/source/browse/AndroidManifest.xml

Project Open Source Site: http://code.google.com/p/futonic-wifioncall/

This isn't the solution but hopefully will give guidance on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. I do already have an Android manifest to go along with the code and I've actually signed and deployed the app to my XOOM. All it does is display a Toast message when I Dock/Undock it.  So, not too useful at the moment, but it doesn't ever crash or die like some of the other Service-based solutions I've tried