# How to toggle "Use Physical Keyboard".

Tags: android, toggle, rfid, virtual-keyboard

I am developing an application where I have RFID reader (emulates keyboard). In some activities I need a virtual keyboard as well. I have discovered that all I need is to toggle "Use Physical Keyboard". That works fine, but when I restart my tablet, this feature is set to default?

Is it possible, if I can insert a toggle somewhere in my code?

Comment: Have a look at [this question][1]... 



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384842/android-3-0-use-physical-keyboard-setting

Comment: That is similar but also has no answer...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to toggle the on-screen keyboard, with the following code:

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

---

In reference, use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

"EditText is a thin veneer over TextView that configures itself to be editable."

To display the on-screen keyboard, all they need do is touch in the textbox. If that box was named "Search" or something similar, I believe it would be more useful to a user than a button.

Comment: will this works also when usb keyboard is plugged in and "Use Physical Keyboard" enabled?