# How to toggle “Use Physical Keyboard”

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, native-methods

I am trying to solve the same thing as the following post posts:

[How to toggle "Use Physical Keyboard".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878153/how-to-toggle-use-physical-keyboard/13231368#13231368)
and
[Switch from physical to software keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244816/switch-from-physical-to-software-keyboard/13231306#13231306)

Basicaly I want to toggle the native option from android to turn the physical keyboard on or off. However, I want to create this button through code.

None of those links have one good answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I will be rather surprised if this is possible.

Comment: The thing is, they already have an option to do that in the system, why not letting that option to be made by the users? :S... I realy hope you are wrong :P

Comment: The reason that I will be surprised if this is possible is that changing input methods (e.g., from soft keyboard A to soft keyboard B) is not possible (for privacy and security reasons), and my guess is that a hardware keyboard will just be considered another input method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I don't see any problem with this since this toggle button only controlls the use or not of the soft-keyboard. If i toggle off the physical keyboard, but I still have it connected, I can still use it to type, the only thing that happens is that the OS will display the soft-keyboard also.

Answer (score 0):

NO, there is currently no way to programmatically accomplish this. The most we can do is detect when a keyboard/scanner is connected and redirect the user to the Input Method selection window, by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged` method in your `Application` class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {

    ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                                  .showInputMethodPicker();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Barcode Scanner detected. Please turn OFF Hardware/Physical keyboard to enable softkeyboard to function.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```